# ¿Que puedo hacer si localmente la funcionalidad del boton imprimir esta bien, pero cuando subo a produccion este ya no funciona?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, typescript, print

Estoy usando la siguiente libria: [print-js](https://printjs.crabbly.com/#documentation).
El problema es el siguiente, tengo un boton imprimir, que funciona correctamente en mi computadora. Pero cuando lo subo al servidor este no imprime.

Esto es lo que ya realice trantando de solucionar:

- Elimine la carpeta `node_modules` para que la libreria se vuelva a instalar
- Reinicie el servidor
- Verifique que la reactividad este funcionando
- Sin exito en poder replicar este error en local
- Y revise el siguiente codigo n veces

```
<button @click.prevent="printBoleta()">
       <span class="has-text-white">Imprimir</span>
</button>

<div id="boleta">
  <h1>Titulo</h1>
  <div>Cuerpo</div>
  <img src="..." />
</div>
```

```
public printBoleta() {
    const style = '@media print {\n' +
      '    #boleta {\n' +
      '      page-break-after: always;\n' +
      '      display: block !important;\n' +
      '    }\n' +
      '    @page { size: auto;  margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0; }\n' +
      '  }';
    print({printable: 'boleta', type: 'html', style, targetStyles: ['*'])}
  }
```

Necesito una pista para poder solucionar este problema. Gracias.

Comment: También necesitamos una pista: un [repro] de lo que tienes hasta el momento.

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente los problemas al subir a producción se deben a problemas con las rutas, permisos de acceso a servicios externos etc.

Imagino que lo has hecho, pero comprueba la consola a ver si hay errores y compártelos. Por otro lado, comprueba la pestaña "Network" para ver si aparecen errores consumiendo servicios.

Con la información que nos das poco más podemos hacer.